# AngularJS creates infinite loop when $http request returns error

Tags: angularjs, http

My problem is pretty simple, but I'm not able to find what out what happens.

All I want to do is read all posts from my local REST API. When I'm responding HTTP 401 from the API, AngularJS keeps repeating the GET requests in an infinite loop.

```
var request = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://jentzschserverdev-46690.onmodulus.net/index.php/issues',
        headers: {
            'Anonymous': true
        }
    };

$http(request)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log('success', data);
        deferred.resolve(data.issues);
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('error');
        deferred.resolve([]);
    });
```

The console tells me:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:63
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14346)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at done (angular.js:9698)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9888)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9829)(anonymous function) 
    @     angular.js:11655(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8596Scope.$apply 
    @ angular.js:14573done @ angular.js:9698completeRequest 
    @ angular.js:9888requestLoaded @ angular.js:9829 angular.js:63
   Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

For better understanding I created a plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/R4tYUHei9vkylPgvAT5B/
(if you uncomment the code in app.js, your browser should crash due to the infinite loop)

Can anybody tell me what's happening here and why??

Comment: It is not firing the get request. You are changing the model and angular is reaching the limit for the dirty checking algorythm

Comment: but I'm not accessing any $scope, and the requests gets fired, I can see it in the network tab

Comment: create a plunker or fiddle so we can figure it out. :-)

Comment: This code is not causing the infinite loop, but it's possible that you have some code that is reacting as a result of the failed http request that is causing it. We need to see more of your code to solve this.

Comment: i'll create a plunker, thank you, so far

Comment: i added a plunker link in the description above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An infinite digest occurs in angular when an object on the scope is [always changing.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) We can't be sure of what's causing this without seeing more of your code.

Not sure if this is causing your problem, but your current `$http.get` is not correctly handling errors, i.e. your HTTP 401

You need to do something like this:

```
$http.get('http://mylocalapi/posts').then(
    function(success) {
        console.log('RESPONSE', success);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('ERROR', error);
    });
```

The `then()` method takes two arguments, a success callback and an error callback. [Read more about $http.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

**UPDATE**

Check out my update to your [plunker.](http://embed.plnkr.co/4a59gIrR5ZOrzngEac4m/app.js)

The infinite digest seemed to come from using a function in your ngRepeat:

```
<li class='issue' ng-repeat="issue in loadIssues()">
  {{issue.name}}
</li>
```

Creating an array on the `$scope` and using it in ngRepeat fixed that:

```
<li class='issue' ng-repeat="issue in issueList">
  {{issue.name}}
</li>
```

Also, `$http` returns a promise itself so you don't need to use `$q`. Simply point the array on the scope to the resolved data:

```
$http(request)
  .success(function(data){
    console.log('success : ', data);
    $scope.issueList = data;
  }).error(function(error) {
    console.log('error : ', error);
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good first answer. OP, we need more details.

Comment: i added a plunker link in the description above

Comment: @MatthiasPosch I updated my answer with a link to a new plunker.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem...what a noob mistake :/